# Material-UI adjust the starting point of the Drawer slide-in animation with offset

Tags: css, material-ui, drawer

I have a drawer component using MUI V5 Drawer component. I did some customization in the createTheme as follow so the left side of the drawer when it is open starts after the side nav. My issue is that the animation for opening/closing the drawer starts/ends at the left edge of the screen view port.

How can I adjust this behavior so the animation starts and ends considering the width of the side nav? Essentially, I want it to appear as if the viewport's left edge begins after the side nav.

```
MuiDrawer: {
        defaultProps: {
            ModalProps: {
                slotProps: {
                    backdrop: {
                        style: {
                            backgroundColor: "transparent",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        styleOverrides: {
            paper: {
                padding: "0px",
                left: sideNavWidth,
                width: drawerWidth,
            },
        },
    },
```